# xcode tab bar keeps showing up

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I am trying to hide the tab bar in my `UIView` this is how my controller looks

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

i keep inserting this code befroe self navigation controller but it doesnt work

```
controller.hides.BottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

I'm unsure whats wrong im sorry im a noob to this

Comment: That’s kind of the point of UITabBarController. From the docs,  "The UITabBarController class implements a specialized view controller that manages a radio-style selection interface. This tab bar interface displays tabs at the bottom of the window for selecting between the different modes and for displaying the views for that mode."

Comment: but isnt there a way to hide it in the login menu of my app

Answer (score 0):

To make a view be hidden, set its `hidden` to YES.

If this is a UINavigationController's tab bar, then you can tell the navigation controller directly to hide the tab bar (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setToolbarHidden:animated:)